# unable to install id3 for php - what is the good alternative?

Tags: php, id3

i have a website (personal site) where i upload my music. i am a dj in clubs and for my mix i use my site to manage my music i create.

so ultimately i want to create mix online so now i have a share hosting and i cannot install the mp3 id3 and i am looking for alternative.

i looked online and found a lot of custom classes where i can read id3 tags.

what i want to know is this:

is it better to use the one that comes with php (which means change my current host) or i should use a script (and which one is the best?)?

thanks

Comment: I have always used [getID3()](http://getid3.sourceforge.net/) and I like it, but this is veering dangerously towards `this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.`

Comment: If you cannot install the extension then your only option is to include a class / script - i dont see anything wrong in using a 3rd party class / script as long as it functions as you want

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Installing a php module (even if it's as easy as yum install or apt-get install) is limited to what you get from the library. Also, if the ID3 change (like upgrading to a different version) you will have to wait  for the library to be updated and re-install it again (unless you want to modify yourself of course).

The PHP library (yes might be a little slower) can be very useful when ID tag are upgraded or modified. You can easily change the PHP code to match what you need and rapidly be able to mange your music library.

I've tried many libraries and I recommend http://getid3.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 11):

compiling is faster, if you need speed compile it.

or you can use: http://getid3.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

I tried to install php's mp3 tag lib, but it seems quite old to me
[How to install php_id3 on wamp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709295/how-to-install-php-id3-on-wamp)

Here is the solution I came up with. Found on stackexchange :
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4961/which-mp3-tagging-tool-for-linux

I installed **the command line tool id3v2**, which does exactly what I need : read **and modify** basic tags (album, artist, title, comment...)

It installs with a simple

```
apt-get install id3v2
```

and is very easy to use. here is an extract from the man page :

```
   -t, --song SONG
          Set the song title information

   -c, --comment DESCRIPTION:COMMENT
          Set the comment information
```

*note :There was also another tool I didn't bother to try, in the same post : "eyeD3"*

Hope this helps.