# How to install php_id3 on wamp?

Tags: php, wampserver, id3

I have tried to find the file people are talking about namely php_id3.dll. I have read that you can install it with the id 3 on wamp but when i google it i get all sorts of scamsites.

Does anyone know where i can find it?

Comment: What do you want to install? No external libraries are needed to build this extension.: http://www.php.net/manual/en/id3.requirements.php

Comment: @Jocelyn:  You still have to [build it](http://www.php.net/manual/en/id3.installation.php).

Comment: The question is about installation, not about building...the question is very unclear to me...

Comment: @Jocelyn well i get PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function id3_get_tag() in my apache error log and i went searching online and read about installing php_id3.dll, i have no experience whatsoever with these extensions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the information you need is in the official PHP documentation:

The error you get (undefined function) means the ID3 extension is not enabled in your PHP configuration:

- [How to change configuration settings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php)

If you don't have the ID3 extension file (it is probably named php_id3.dll or something similar), you must either find a place to download it, or build it yourself from source.

- [ID3 installation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/id3.installation.php)
- [Building on Windows](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.building.php)
- [Installation of PECL extensions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.php)
- [Installing a PHP extension on Windows](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.windows.php)
- [Downloading PECL extensions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.downloads.php)
- [PECL Package ID3](http://pecl.php.net/package/id3)
- [Building from source](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.building.php)

Answer (score 2):

Download php-id3 from https://github.com/JamesHeinrich/getID3

Move it your project location, you require to include the file.
Ex: require("getid3/getid3.php");

Answer (score 1):

> A DLL for this PECL extension is currently unavailable. See also the
>   building on Windows section.

Source : http://www.php.net/manual/en/id3.installation.php

Answer (score 0):

I was expecting something like apt-get install php5-id3v2, but this lib seems way to old and abandonned for that.  It may still work, but is not very intuitive to install, for sure.

So I came up with another solution, which I found on stackexchange :
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4961/which-mp3-tagging-tool-for-linux

I installed **the command line tool id3v2**, which does exactly what I need : read **and modify** basic tags (album, artist, title, comment...)

It installs with a simple

```
apt-get install id3v2
```

and is very easy to use. here is an extract from the man page :

```
   -t, --song SONG
          Set the song title information

   -c, --comment DESCRIPTION:COMMENT
          Set the comment information
```

*note :There was also another tool I didn't bother to try, in the same post : "eyeD3"*

Hope this helps.