# I try to get mp3 file details using php id3_get_tag but it give me error

Tags: php

I want to print mp3 file details like title, artist, album, year, genre.
so I use  `id3_get_tag` in php . But when I try to run this code it gives me error.

I dont know how to get details of mp3 file .

My php code:

```html
<?php
$tag = id3_get_tag( "file.mp3");
print_r($tag);
?>
```

When I run this code. I got this error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function id3_get_tag() in
>   C:\wamp\www\uploader\test1.php on line 2

Comment: undefined function id3_get_tag() http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709295/how-to-install-php-id3-on-wamp

Answer (score 0):

The error you get (undefined function) means the ID3 extension is not enabled in your PHP configuration:

Comment: how to i enable id3 extension in my php  configuration ?

Comment: i cant understand how can do this. can u provide me any video tutorials  or any simple tutorials. please

Answer (score 0):

The error you get (undefined function) means the ID3 extension is not enabled in your PHP configuration:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php

If you don't have the ID3 extension you should install it by downloading or building it yourself from source.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/id3.installation.php