# php_id3.dll for PHP can not be find

Tags: php

In the internet I can find a lot of informations about php_id3.dll developed by THE PHP Group. But the most links are not longer exist anymore.
I am looking for a php_id3.dll for windows server 2019, to access informations from a mp3 file.

Could somebody explain me, what the mystery about this php_id3.dll is?
Is it not longer available?

Is there another solution, where I can get id3 information from a php program?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install php\_id3 on wamp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709295/how-to-install-php-id3-on-wamp)

Answer (score 1):

The ID3-related pages do not exist on the official PHP website anymore, but you can easily have a look on them using the web archive, e.g.: https://web.archive.org/web/20200314011819/https://www.php.net/manual/en/id3.installation.php

The official PECL page of this old extension is here: https://pecl.php.net/package/id3. But it clearly says it is not maintained anymore.

Still, you can find the DLL in a few places: https://github.com/maryo/php-5.5-windows-extensions/tree/master/php_id3-0.2-5.5-vc11-x86 or https://fossies.org/windows/www/pecl-5.2.6-Win32.zip/.

These being said, even if you manage to make one of the DDLs work, you should most probably use something that is not 15 years old.

After a quick search, there are several ID3-capable libraries on packagist, I would start testing the most popular one: https://packagist.org/?query=ID3